# What's the difference between a covariate and a feature in a machine learning context?

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, terminology

After doing some research I couldn't really find a clear difference between those two terms when considering machine learning except that a covariate has to be continuous.

Comment: Covariates/features are synonymous.  The former is preferred by statisticians, while the latter is preferred by the machine learning community

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of confusion of terms in moving between statistics and machine learning.  These two terms are essentially synonyms.

*Covariate* implies a separate, related, focal variable (e.g., the dependent variable in regression). You can talk about *features* without a focal variable in mind.  But sometimes people talk about covariates without a specified dependent variable, and there's nothing wrong with calling your independent regression variables "features".

> a covariate has to be continuous

...that is not true.